# How much points do you need for each Level

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

How much points do you need in Call of Duty Black Ops 3 for each level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Each prestige has the same rules in points and levels

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/blackops3/comments/3tp7gm/xp_needed_for_each_level/

Comment: Where'd you get that table?  It's important to provide proper attribution.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/blackops3/comments/3tp7gm/xp_needed_for_each_level/

Comment: I even checked if it's right